# How to parse string and array JSON data in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have the following JSON text that I need to parse to get in my Android application title (Main title) and  title (sub title), description, imageHref.

```
{
  "title":"Flowers",
  "rows":[
     {
        "title":"Azalea",
        "description":"Beautiful large royal purple flowers adorn attractive satiny green leaves that turn orange/red in cold weather. Grows to up to 18 feet, or prune annually to shorten.",
        "imageHref":"http://...../../b/california_snow.jpg"
     },
     {
        "title":"Tibouchina",
        "description":"Blooms in summer, 20-35 inches high. Fertilize regularly for best results. Full sun, drought tolerant.",
        "imageHref":"http://...../../b/california_snow.jpg"
     }
}
```

Please help me to get the required code. I am using JSONparser.

Comment: We are not here to do your Home work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson=gsonBuilder.create();
gson.fromJson(<return type>,<expected type>);
```